# How can I test Cross Domain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-domain

When writing apps in HTML and/or JavaScript for Pebble and Phonegap Build (both of which allow cross domain requests) I find I have to compile the app each time I want to test the code since the browsers I have used disable CORS.

Are there any browsers or other HTML and/or JavaScript testers (?) which allow cross domain scripting?

---

Note that a workaround such as JSONP isn't necessary here, I just need to test code which works with Phonegap or Pebble etc.

Comment: Respond with proper cors headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you the one who developed the backend code? If so you can add header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', if no you can just use google chrome with extensions like [allow-control-allow-origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) and [advanced-rest-client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

Comment: I provided the correct and clear answer, it is not good to vote my answer like that.

Comment: No, unfortunately. I am trying to access some APIs and Stack Exchange